# Can't figure out where my routing error is coming from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am trying to implement a polymorphic association for the first time and I'm running into a little bit of trouble.

I am trying to allow users to leave a note on a contact or organization. But after I submit a note I run into a routing error.

[Here is the error I'm receiving (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMWz4.png)

Here are my **routes**:

[Here are my routes (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnapS.png)

Here is my **routes.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :organizations do
    resources :contacts do 
      resources :notes, module: :contacts
    end
    resources :notes, module: :organizations
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Here is my **notes_controller.rb** file:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @note = @noteable.notes.new note_params

    redirect_to @noteable, notice: "Your note was successful!!!"
  end

  private

  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:note_title, :note_body)
  end
end
```

Here is my **contacts/notes_controller.rb** file:

```
class Contacts::NotesController < ApplicationController

  private

  def set_noteable
    @noteable = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
  end
end
```

Here is my **oranizations/notes_controller.rb** file:

```
class Organizations::NotesController < ApplicationController

  private

  def set_noteable
    @noteable = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
  end
end
```

Here is my **view/notes/_form.html.rb** file:

```
<h1>New Note</h1>
<%= form_for [noteable, Note.new] do |form| %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :note_title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :note_title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :note_body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :note_body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

If you need anything else, I will provide it! Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
resources :organizations do
  resources :contacts do 
    resources :notes, module: :contacts
  end
  resources :notes, module: :organizations
end
```

to these lines:

```
resources :organizations do
  resources :contacts do 
    resources :notes
  end
  resources :notes
end
```

You don't need the module there since they are already scoped by the parent resource.

Also move the `contacts/notes_controller.rb` to `organizations/contacts/notes_controller.rb`. Make sure you also move the view into the corresponding folder.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting an error. Now it's a NoMethodError in NotesController#create error and the error message is "undefined method `notes' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: You need to move the set_noteable method from the other controllers into this one and use a before_action filter.